# CSS Box-shadow artifact on certain iOS devices with chrome

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, artifacts

I've tried to search for some answers here and some other place but I can not seem to find. The issue is very inconsistent and I am not sure what to do. It seems to appear only on iOS devices using chrome, but not on safari, not on android based chrome nor the different versions of firefox.

I am building my web portfolio in VueJS, so all the prefixes are fixed by webpack. I have the following code for my button (SCSS):

```
.hide-component-btn{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(240, 248, 248);
        border: none;
        color: $default-text-color;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color ease-in-out 0.2s;
        &:hover, &:active{
            color:white;
            background-color: $component-secondary-color;
            i{
                color:white;
            }
        }   
    }
    .hide-component-btn-shadow-left{
        box-shadow: inset 13px 13px 0px -5px $component-secondary-color;
    }
    .hide-component-btn-shadow-right{
        box-shadow: inset -13px 13px 0px -5px $component-secondary-color;
    }
```

The last 2 mentioned classes `.hide-component-btn-shadow-left` and `.hide-component-btn-shadow-right`, are shadows that are applied, one at a time, based on a variable that determines if the user is using the app/webpage with the left hand or right hand. The user can click/tap on a button with an arrow to change the main navigation button position which in turn changes the big thin button (that you can see on the screenshots) , making it easier to be used with bigger screens.

The image below show the correct expected behavior. You can see the left portion of the screen has the tall and thin button that I previously mentioned (which serves to hide a component). The screenshot shows a button on the left. But it  could also appear on the right side if the user would be right-handed, in that case the tall button would appear on the right side and the content would appear on the left side, as following.

Left hand use case:

[image: Left hand use case]

Right hand use case:

[image: Right hand use case]

The previously screenshots show how it is supposed too look like on most browsers and resolutions (expected behavior).

The following screens shows when the artifact is present, in other words, unexpected behavior (take notice on the line that does along the right side of the button):

[image]

And here is a screenshot from a iOS(iPhone 7) device using chrome, showing the same exact behavior (the arrow shows the artifact that is present, along the right edge of the button, same as in the previous screenshot):

[image]

I can not understand what could actually provoke this artifact and only specific for iOS and chrome. I tried changing the background color to a different one, to transparent and nothing. The only way to actually remove the artifact is by removing the box-shadow property, which I kind of need it. Any suggestions ?
You can check it by yourself at [calexandru.com](http://calexandru.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understood your problem exactly. But for `box-shadow` you should always use `-webkit-box-shadow /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */` and `-moz-box-shadow /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */`, hope it works for you.

Comment: @SMAKSS the webkit is applied automatically by webpack, but thanks for the comment. I'll try to edit and make it more specific.